# when i use dismissviewcontrolleranimated , i got exc_bad_access

Tags: ios

I got an error `exc_bad_access`,when i use `dismissviewcontrolleranimated`

the `presentViewController` code is:

```
TestViewController *testViewController=[[TestViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:testViewController];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presentViewController is finish");
}];
```

but,when i remove `UINavigationController` ,is error is disappear.

like this:

```
TestViewController *testViewController=[[TestViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:testViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presentViewController is finish");
}];
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: No, I did not use storyboard, only xib

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` have Push and Pull transitions and you are trying to apply `Modal Transition` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Present View Controller is presented over a "Root View Controller" not a UINavigationController. 
You should present your VC from the Parent VC or Base VC like this

```
TestViewController *testViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIDofViewController"];//set the storyboard ID of the TestViewController in your storyboard by selecting attribute inspector after selecting the view controller.
    [self presentViewController:testViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"presentViewController is finish");
}];
```

This is the correct way to present a VC from another VC.